# calling function in difference ways

Tags: javascript, typescript

what is difference between

```
//debounce.ts
function debounce(func: Function, timeout = 3000) {
  let timer: any

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(func)
    }, timeout)
  }
}

function callDebounce(apiCallFunc: Function) {
  const yui = debounce(() => {
    apiCallFunc()
  })

  return yui()
}

export default callDebounce
```

and

```
//debounce.ts
import apiCallFunc from "./controller"

function debounce(func: Function, timeout = 3000) {
  let timer: any

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(func)
    }, timeout)
  }
}

export default debounce(() => {
  apiCallFunc()
})
```

if I import this file and call it three times tandemly,
in the first one func will be called tree times after 3sec, and at second one it will be called just once after 3sec. but I dont know why!

actually I want a function to which I can pass many different callbacks, and it will run only the last one,but i dont want to get my apiCallFunk with importing it like the second one. i want my apiCallFunk as argument. because of this I have to use first one.

the use:

```
//controller.ts
import debounce from "./debounce.ts"

export apiCallFunc(){
//some comde here
}

onSearch(){
 debounce(apicallFunc())
}
```

Comment: First one returns a function that *when called* will return a debounced function. Which is basically useless as it circumvents the debouncing. Second just gives you a debounced function.

Comment: The first exports a function while the second exports the return value of the `debounce()` function (which is `undefined`)

Comment: if i have to use first one, how can i write it to act like second one? @slebetman

Comment: `return yui;` instead of `return yui();`

Comment: @slebetman `debounce` returns a function as well

Comment: if i use yui insteade of yui() it wont be work!

Comment: @VLAZ "*when called will return a debounced function*" - not even that, it will create and immediately call the debounced function, then return `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code with your first snippet is calling `debounce` three times, creating three different `yui` functions that are debounced individually (each of them being a closure with its own `let timer`), and then calls each of them once.

The code with your second snippet is calling `debounce` once, then calls that debounced function three times, causing the timer mechanism to prevent two of the logs.

---

> Actually I want a function to which I can pass many different callbacks, and it will run only the last one, because of this I have to use first one.

No, you need the second approach where `debouce` is only called once and a single `timer` is created. What you *really* want is a `debounce` function that passes through arguments:

```
function debounce(func: Function, timeout = 3000) {
  let timer: number | undefined;
  return function(...args) => {
//                ^^^^^^^
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args)
//                     ^^^^
    }, timeout)
  }
}

export default debounce(argFunc => {
//                      ^^^^^^^
  argFunc()
})
```

However, you should not export that `debounce()` call, it creates a module-level state and it will be impossible to create multiple different debounced functions with separate state or timeout lenghts (e.g. for multiple instances of the component). Calling `debouce` immediately and exporting the result is the same as writing a module

```
let timer: number | undefined;

export default function(argFunc) => {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(argFunc, 3000)
}
```

Don't do that. Instead, export the `debounce` function itself, and then call it in your component where `onSearch` is needed:

```
// debounce.ts
export default function debounce(func: Function, timeout = 3000) {
  let timer: number | undefined;
  return function(...args) => {
//                ^^^^^^^
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args)
//                     ^^^^
    }, timeout)
  }
}
```

```
// controller.ts
import debounce from "./debounce.ts"

function apiCallFunc(){
  …
}

onSearch = debounce(apicallFunc);
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: so i have to use the first one because i want to add some other codes to callDebounce. how can i write it to act like the second one?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you want the behaviour of the second, then use that code? Other code *can* call your exported function?

Comment: actually i want to get "func" as argument instead of console.log()

Comment: You mean you want a function to which you can pass many different callbacks, and it will run only the last one? Can you edit your question to show you would like to import and call that?

Comment: why do we use "this" in func.apply(this, args) ?

Comment: @ZahraEsfandiary You can also use `undefined` if you don't care about the receiver (the `this` value inside `func`). Counterquestion: why did you use `func` in your original code?

Comment: I used func because i thought that i can use it as argument in debounce(func=> {
  func()
})
but it didnt work